# Issue with time-analysis

Tags: big-o

I'm teaching myself data structures, and am on a section giving a brief outline of time analysis. The following problem was given:

```
"Each of the following are formulas for the number of operations in some
 algorithm. Express each formula in big-O notation."
```

The problem then goes on to give multiple scenarios. One was:

```
g.) The number of times that n can be divided by 10 before dropping below
    1.0.
```

(Note: It doesn't state what n is exactly, so I'm assuming it's just some input size. But I don't think it matters in terms of how the problem is stated)

I reasoned that as this would relate to its order of magnitude, it should just be log n. However, the text says that it should be quadratic. Is there something I am missing?

Any help to help my thinking would be greatly appreciated.